# In wordpress , how can I make page be related with post-type?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

First of all, I'm not good at english. Sorry :( .

Hello! I'm developing woocommerce theme. And I meet problem. Please see this screenshot !.

[image: The anchor href]

When I Click The Return shop Btn -> browser request this query below!.

[image]

The query changed!!! from [~~?page_id=693] to [~~?post_type=product] 
How This Can Happened??

[image]

And this is the shop page(id = 693) !...I'm so surprised! Please help me.

Comment: I don’t know Woocommerce, but it looks like the shop simply collects all products in this custom post type and shows the corresponding archive page as store front, could that be?

Comment: so, how custom post type( products ) are related with page 693?

Comment: See Alice's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your woocommerce settings you have assigned shop page(693). That's why that page 693 is behaving like a shop page, and it's permalink is   [~~?post_type=product].

If you want to show all of a certain post type in your own page (template), copy archive.php and rename it as - `'archive-{your_post_type}.php'`. This will load your post types only. Now change the template as per your need.